# Colorbox close button cant see

Tags: html, colorbox

I was playing around with colorbox demo and seeing how it works. I wanted to make a simple colorbox for a login page got it to work and fine accept whats bugging me is I can't seem to get the close button to show the image I want and its driving me nuts. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong though. I was wondering if its because I strip out some line of code but I only removed the slide show functions. Can someone point me out what I'm doing wrong. The button is there I just can't see it ....

```
/*
    ColorBox Core Style:
    The following CSS is consistent between example themes and should not be altered.
*/
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
#cboxOverlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxMiddleLeft, #cboxBottomLeft{clear:left;}
#cboxContent{position:relative;}
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto;}
#cboxTitle{margin:0;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
.cboxPhoto{float:left; margin:auto; border:0; display:block; max-width:none;}
.cboxIframe{width:100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0;}
#colorbox, #cboxContent, #cboxLoadedContent{box-sizing:content-box;}

/* 
    User Style:
    Change the following styles to modify the appearance of ColorBox.  They are
    ordered & tabbed in a way that represents the nesting of the generated HTML.
*/
#cboxOverlay{background:url('overlay.jpg') repeat 0 0;}
#colorbox{}
#cboxTopLeft{width:21px; height:21px; background:url('overlay.jpg') no-repeat -101px 0;}
#cboxTopRight{width:21px; height:21px; background:url('overlay.jpg') no-repeat -130px 0;}
#cboxBottomLeft{width:21px; height:21px; background:url('overlay.jpg') no-repeat -101px -29px;}
#cboxBottomRight{width:21px; height:21px; background:url('overlay.jpg') no-repeat -130px -29px;}
#cboxMiddleLeft{width:21px; background:url('overlay.jpg') left top repeat-y;}
#cboxMiddleRight{width:21px; background:url('overlay.jpg') right top repeat-y;}
#cboxTopCenter{height:21px; background:url('overlay.jpg') 0 0 repeat-x;}
#cboxBottomCenter{height:21px; background:url('overlay.jpg') 0 -29px repeat-x;}
#cboxContent{background:#fff; overflow:hidden;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay{background:url('loading.gif') no-repeat center center;}
#cboxLoadingGraphic{background:url('loading.gif') no-repeat center center;}
#cboxClose{position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; background:url('xbutton.png') no-repeat -25px 0; width:25px; height:25px; text-indent:-9999px;}
#cboxClose:hover{background-position:-25px -25px;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using colorbox plugin from this [site](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)

Then the errors will be one of the follows

1. Check your js file for the line:35

> close: "close",

Make sure that you have given that in jquery.colorbox.js

1. Check your css file line:45

> position:absolute;bottom:0; right:0;

Has been correctly entered on script

As you mentioned by playing there is a chance you may deleted the term

> position:relative;

in the line:8

Comment: yea I finally realize what I was doing wrong accidentally deleted something in js file ..